# Pushing pointers to followers with the metadata (MySQL Query)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I’ve seen the following question on **StackOverflow**, **[Intelligent MySQL GROUP BY for Activity Streams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004322/intelligent-mysql-group-by-for-activity-streams)** posted by **Christian Owens 12/12/12**.

So I decided to try out the same approach, make two tables similar to those of his. And then I pretty much copied his query which I do understand. 
This is what I get out from my sandbox:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0
            [user_id] => 1
            [action] => published_post
            [object_id] => 776286559146635
            [object_type] => post
            [stream_date] => 2015-11-24 12:28:09
            [rows_in_group] => 1
            [in_collection] => 0
        )

)
```

I am curious, since looking at the results in **Owens** question, I am not able to fully get something, and does he perform additional queries to grab the actual metadata? And if yes, does this mean that one can do it from that single query or does one need to run different optimized sub-queries and then loop through the arrays of data to render the stream itself.

Thanks a lot in advanced.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0
            [user_id] => 1
            [fullname] => David Anderson
            [action] => hearted
            [object_id] => array (
              [id] => 3438983
              [title] => Grand Theft Auto
              [Category] => Games
            )
            [object_type] => product
            [stream_date] => 2015-11-24 12:28:09
            [rows_in_group] => 1
            [in_collection] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96652/discussion-on-question-by-john-smith-pushing-pointers-to-followers-with-the-meta).

Comment: Do you really need that array after `object_id` or the `title` and `category` can be keys from the array at position 0? Can an object have more than one title and more than one category?

Comment: @FelyppOliveira Think JSON Objects.

Comment: You can't get nested arrays only with mysql functions in PHP you need to get the `object_data` serialized somehow, or just LEFT JOIN the 'object' table and select the required fields from there.

Comment: @venimus, maybe I should have posted a JSON document here instead.

Comment: @venimus, maybe this makes sense to you: http://blog.outsourcing-partners.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/json_example.png

Comment: what I mean is that mysql returns flat structures for each row. Without additional parsing of it you cannot get nested arrays. You could either select each field or concatanate them like in the 1st answer (which is a serialization), then parse the result and unserialize that field to make your desired structure

Comment: @venimus, do you know any website that shows some examples of this? I am using PHP PDO to connect to the DB and grab results.

Comment: How I get your question you need 1 query to rule them all. But it is not clear what your `object` is. Are these objects stored in many tables or just single one. In timelines you can interact with different objects. If it is 1 table you just left join it. If there are many unrelated tables, then you need to make something very specific but you need to provide their structure too.

Comment: @venimus: Re: "But it is not clear what your object is.", an object can be anything, a post, a blog post, a photo, a status update etc. You get it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In "pseudo" code you need something like this

```
$result = $pdo->query('
    SELECT stream.*,
       object.*,
       COUNT(stream.id) AS rows_in_group,
       GROUP_CONCAT(stream.id) AS in_collection
    FROM stream
    INNER JOIN follows ON stream.user_id = follows.following_user
    LEFT JOIN object ON stream.object_id = object.id
    WHERE follows.user_id = '0'
    GROUP BY stream.user_id,
         stream.verb,
         stream.object_id,
         stream.type,
         date(stream.stream_date)
    ORDER BY stream.stream_date DESC
');
```

then parse the result and convert it in php

```
$data = array(); // this will store the end result
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    // here for each row you get the keys and put it in a sub-array
    // first copy the selected `object` data into a sub array
    $row['object_data']['id'] = $row['object.id'];
    $row['object_data']['title'] = $row['object.title'];

    // remove the flat selected keys
    unset($row['object.id']);
    unset($row['object.title']);

      ...
    $data[] = $row; // move to the desired array
}
```

you should get

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0
            [user_id] => 1
            [fullname] => David Anderson
            [verb] => hearted
            [object_data] => array (
              [id] => 3438983
              [title] => Grand Theft Auto
              [Category] => Games
            )
            [type] => product
            [stream_date] => 2015-11-24 12:28:09
            [rows_in_group] => 1
            [in_collection] => 1
        )

)
```

Comment: How do they make this: http://www.gobiznow.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/facebook-social-graph-json-php-01.jpg, take the cover => array part, is it retrieved with one single mysql query?

Comment: Can you give me a better example, and I'll award you the bounty?

Comment: they probably join the "cover" table. Like in the example instead of "object" table join "cover". and similar in the "while loop"

Comment: If you use a ORM layer it will produce such data automatically. Consider using Doctrine. This is called "hydration" - the process of converting DB raw data into objects (or other complex structures). Doctrine is the most widely used ORM currently and is well documented, it is usually supported by all major frameworks. You can use it as a library without a framework. In the Doctrine docs there are examples.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you want a query where you can return the data you're actually able to get plus the user `fullname` and the data related to the `object_id`.

I think that the best effort would be to include some subqueries in your query to extract these data:

- Fullname: something like `(SELECT fullname FROM users WHERE id = stream.user_id) AS fullname`... or some modified version using the `stream.user_id`, as we can't identify in your schema where this fullname comes from;
- Object Data: something like `(SELECT CONCAT_WS(';', id, title, category_name) FROM objects WHERE id = stream.object_id) AS object_data`. Just as the fullname, we can't identify in your schema where these object data comes from, but I'm assuming it's an objects table.

One object may have just one `title` and may have just one `category`. In this case, the Object Data subquery works great. I don't think an object can have more than one title, but it's possible to have more than one category. In this case, you should `GROUP_CONCAT` the category names and take one of the two paths:

- Replace the `category_name` in the `CONCAT_WS` for the `GROUP_CONCAT` of all categories names;
- Select a new column `categories` (just a name suggestion) with the subquery which `GROUP_CONCAT` all categories names;

If your tables were like te first two points of my answer, a query like this may select the data, just needing a proper parse (split) in PHP:

```
SELECT 
  MAX(stream.id) as id, 
  stream.user_id,
  (select fullname from users where id = stream.user_id) as fullname,
  stream.verb,
  stream.object_id,
  (select concat_ws(';', id, title, category_name) from objects where id = stream.object_id) as object_data,
  stream.type,
  date(stream.stream_date) as stream_date,
  COUNT(stream.id) AS rows_in_group,
  GROUP_CONCAT(stream.id) AS in_collection
FROM stream
INNER JOIN follows ON 1=1
  AND stream.user_id = follows.following_user
WHERE 1=1
  AND follows.user_id = '0'
GROUP BY 
  stream.user_id,
  stream.verb,
  stream.object_id,
  stream.type,
  date(stream.stream_date)
ORDER BY stream.stream_date DESC;
```

In ANSI SQL you can't reference columns not listed in your `GROUP BY`, unless they're in aggregate functions. So, I included the `id` as an aggregation.

Comment: Thanks for your answer response. It kind of seems like I initially thought, a left-join or inner join of some kind. I want to remind you that this is what I want to achieve as part of this, see this as an example: http://blog.outsourcing-partners.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/08/json_example.png

Comment: @JohnSmith where should these `users` go in your expected result? As you are grouping the data by `stream.user_id`, you'll get a single user per row...