# Pull more records based on IDs in comma separated list returned by GROUP_CONCAT

Tags: mysql, sql

Is it possible to pull more records based on IDs in comma separated list return by GROUP_CONCAT? Is a LEFT JOIN possible here? If so, how can it be done. I am constantly failing at figuring this out, in addition, I've googled a lot already.

**I have these two tables:**

```
CREATE Table users (
  id BIGINT(100) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
  password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE Table articles (
  id BIGINT(100) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  author_id BIGINT(100) NOT NULL, 
  title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
  content TEXT, 
  published DATETIME NOT NULL
);
```

**Insert:**

```
INSERT INTO users (username, password) 
VALUES ('Bob', '5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99');

INSERT INTO users (username, password) 
VALUES ('David', '630bf032efe4507f2c57b280995925a9');

INSERT INTO articles (author_id, title, content, published)
VALUES ('1', 'Science 101', 'Science is the concerted human effort to understand, or to understand better, the history of the natural world and how the natural world works, with observable physical evidence as the basis of that understanding1. It is done through observation of natural phenomena, and/or through experimentation that tries to simulate natural processes under controlled conditions.',
        '2015-11-30 09:18:43');

INSERT INTO articles (author_id, title, content, published)
VALUES ('1', 'Health Care', 'Health care or healthcare is the maintenance or improvement of health via the diagnosis, treatment, and prevention of disease, illness, injury, and other physical and mental impairments in human beings.',
        '2016-01-10 15:20:43');

INSERT INTO articles (author_id, title, content, published)
VALUES ('2', 'Physics 101', 'Physics is a natural science based on experiments, measurements and mathematical analysis with the purpose of finding quantitative physical laws for everything from the nanoworld of the microcosmos to the planets, solar systems and galaxies that occupy the macrocosmos.',
        '2016-01-17 14:18:43');
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT 
  articles.id, 
  articles.author_id,
  users.username,
  COUNT(articles.id) AS number_of_articles,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT articles.id) AS articles_published
FROM articles 
LEFT JOIN users ON articles.author_id = users.id
GROUP BY articles.author_id 
ORDER BY articles.published DESC;
```

**Result:**

```
id  author_id   username    number_of_articles  articles_published
3   2           David       1                   3
2   1           Bob         2                   2,1
```

**Expected result:**

```
Bob's articles

Health Care
Health care or healthcare is the maintenance or improvement of health via the diagnosis, treatment, and prevention of disease, illness, injury, and other physical and mental impairments in human beings.

Science 101
Science is the concerted human effort to understand, or to understand better, the history of the natural world and how the natural world works, with observable physical evidence as the basis of that understanding1. It is done through observation of natural phenomena, and/or through experimentation that tries to simulate natural processes under controlled conditions.

------

David's articles

Physics 101
Physics is a natural science based on experiments, measurements and mathematical analysis with the purpose of finding quantitative physical laws for everything from the nanoworld of the microcosmos to the planets, solar systems and galaxies that occupy the macrocosmos.

-----
```

SQLfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/964ed/1

Comment: Please edit your question and show what results you want to see.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, please see my latest EDIT. Thanks!

Comment: Typically, issues of data display are best handled in a presentation layer/application level code (e.g. PHP), assuming that's available.

Comment: @Strawberry, so I can not use mysql to give me a structured output so that I can easily loop the result with PHP can output it as I expect it? Can I use articles_published in the same query with JOINS and IN (...) to get the result organized and grouped?

Comment: If you're looping the result with PHP, then forget about the GROUP_CONCAT.

Comment: @Strawberry, why should I forget GROUP_CONCAT?

Comment: Because to a rough approximation, there is no problem in SQL for which GROUP_CONCAT is the solution. In this instance, you're taking a normalised data set, and compressing it into a malformed array, which PHP then needs to disentangle. Just spit out the data set as a well-formed array, and parse the array in PHP.

Comment: @Strawberry, are you able to show me how something like this is done?

Comment: PHP's really not my forte... but I can shove some thoughts together...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a crude example...

```
<?php

include('path/to/connection/stateme.nts');

$query = "
  SELECT DISTINCT a.id
                , a.author_id
                , u.username
             FROM articles a
             LEFT
             JOIN users u
               ON u.id = a.author_id
            ORDER
               BY u.username
                , a.published DESC;
";
$array = array();
$result = mysqli_query($db,$query);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
  $array[] = $row;
} // end of while loop

foreach($array as $key){
$new_array[$key['username']][] = $key['id'];
}
print_r($new_array);
?>
```

This would spit out an array like this...

```
Array
(
    [Bob] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => 1
        )

    [David] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
        )

)

...
```

where username is the key to a sub-array, and the number of articles is equal to the number of items in that sub-array (apologies if my terminology is wrong)

Comment: This is something I'v done before posting here! Manipulating the array with PHP.

Comment: So I guess the representation of the final output is manipulated at the application level, and there's no other way to get it like that from mysql. So it confirms that what I did initially before posting here was correct and in the correct direction. Thanks @Strawberry.

Comment: @JohnSmith It's not that 'there's no other way', but given that you're manipulating the output in PHP anyway, what's the benefit of your approach? I agree to some extent that if you were doing some more  complicated aggregation of data then there might be an argument for using GROUP_CONCAT, but that's about it. Generally, the trend these days seems to be to construct arrays and then spit them out as json for manipulating with javascript.

Comment: "if you were doing some more complicated aggregation of data then there might be an argument for using GROUP_CONCAT"
@Strawberry what about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004322/intelligent-mysql-group-by-for-activity-streams, why is he using GROUP_CONCAT? And how does he use the group concatenated result to pull more rows of data?

Comment: @JohnSmith Because he's not as smart as you are. He's parsing a string nested inside an array. You're parsing an array nested inside an array. That's smarter, right?, because you can use the same logic to parse every dimension of the multi-dimensional array.

Comment: Sounds like BS? Seriously! Why is he doing it that way?

Comment: I did, he didn't respond to me. Months ago, So you think this approach is smarter? In what way would you argue?

Comment: I've already answered that. You're entitled to disagree with my answer.

Comment: "You're entitled to disagree with my answer. " I need better argument and explanation to "why"?

Comment: I'm not that interested in what you think you need.