# MySQL: Aggregating and Grouping

Tags: php, mysql

**This is a little bit of a MySQL and PHP issue here.**

**I have these two tables:**

```
CREATE Table users (
  id BIGINT(100) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  username VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
  password VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE Table articles (
  id BIGINT(100) AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  author_id BIGINT(100) NOT NULL, 
  title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, 
  content TEXT, 
  published DATETIME NOT NULL
);
```

**Insert:**

```
INSERT INTO users (username, password) 
VALUES ('Bob', '5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99');

INSERT INTO users (username, password) 
VALUES ('David', '630bf032efe4507f2c57b280995925a9');

INSERT INTO articles (author_id, title, content, published)
VALUES ('1', 'Science 101', 'Science is the concerted human effort to understand, or to understand better, the history of the natural world and how the natural world works, with observable physical evidence as the basis of that understanding1. It is done through observation of natural phenomena, and/or through experimentation that tries to simulate natural processes under controlled conditions.',
        '2015-11-30 09:18:43');

INSERT INTO articles (author_id, title, content, published)
VALUES ('1', 'Health Care', 'Health care or healthcare is the maintenance or improvement of health via the diagnosis, treatment, and prevention of disease, illness, injury, and other physical and mental impairments in human beings.',
        '2016-01-10 15:20:43');

INSERT INTO articles (author_id, title, content, published)
VALUES ('2', 'Physics 101', 'Physics is a natural science based on experiments, measurements and mathematical analysis with the purpose of finding quantitative physical laws for everything from the nanoworld of the microcosmos to the planets, solar systems and galaxies that occupy the macrocosmos.',
        '2016-01-17 14:18:43');
```

**Query:**

```
SELECT 
  articles.id, 
  articles.author_id,
  users.username,
  COUNT(articles.id) AS number_of_articles,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT articles.id) AS articles_published
FROM articles 
LEFT JOIN users ON articles.author_id = users.id
GROUP BY articles.author_id 
ORDER BY articles.published DESC;
```

**Result:**

```
id  author_id   username    number_of_articles  articles_published
3   2           David       1                   3
2   1           Bob         2                   2,1
```

**Here's my SQLfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/964ed/1**

**The column articles_published holds the ids as seen above, using those ids, I want to grab the additional information, such as: the title and the content of each article belonging to respective author.**

I've read somewhere the explode (PHP) can be used, but this only gives you an array of IDs, not the result I out for. I want this aggregated, as displayed (see **Expected result section**).

```
$r = $result[1]['articles_published']; //2,1 
$array = explode(',',$r);
print_r($array);

//Output:
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 1
)
```

The array containing the results after explode, doesn't really help me get the additional results, such as: title and content of the articles with ID 1 and 2 in the articles table.

**Expected result:**

```
David wrote 1 article

Physics 101
Physics is a natural science based on experiments, measurements and mathematical analysis with the purpose of finding quantitative physical laws for everything from the nanoworld of the microcosmos to the planets, solar systems and galaxies that occupy the macrocosmos.

-----

Bob wrote 2 articles

Health Care
Health care or healthcare is the maintenance or improvement of health via the diagnosis, treatment, and prevention of disease, illness, injury, and other physical and mental impairments in human beings.

Science 101
Science is the concerted human effort to understand, or to understand better, the history of the natural world and how the natural world works, with observable physical evidence as the basis of that understanding1. It is done through observation of natural phenomena, and/or through experimentation that tries to simulate natural processes under controlled conditions.

------
```

**EDIT:** Yes, as for the MySQL, I am aware that I can do it (see below), but I am out for aggregating and grouping stuff through MySQL.

```
SELECT users.username
     , articles.title 
     , articles.content
  FROM users
INNER
  JOIN articles 
    ON articles.author_id = users.id
ORDER 
    BY users.username
     , articles.title
```

Comment: You can not get the desired result set from a single query, what  you are doing is correct but you have to do one more thing to get the articles, you have ids of article in variable. `$r = $result[1]['articles_published'];` bestway is to write a sql query and gel all the articles from that query so that you can print them. 
`select * from artiles where id in ($r)`

and by the way, explode only converts a string to array, you data base returned 2,1 explode can only split them, you have to retrieve data on behalf of these ids. 

not a pro but hope it can help.

Comment: @AmitSarwara, thanks for your response. I have to admit, this sounds very stupid: "you data base returned 2,1 explode can only split them, you have to retrieve data on behalf of these ids. not a pro but hope it can help", because, I already knew that, that's the reason I asked here, looks like you TL;DR my question. As for the code, "select * from artiles where id in ($r)", I know that too, the problem is that it has to run in a loop against the DB and that is very bad. $r has to change index for the next to grab.

Comment: @johy smith sorry for my dumbness. But i have one other solution too. If you want to use single query and want to get the result. Use subquery to achive your result set.

Comment: @AmitSarwara, explain.

Comment: Like this query, ~SELECT users.username
     , articles.title 
     , articles.content, (select count(article_id) from articles a where a.author_id=users.id) as count
  FROM users
INNER
  JOIN articles 
    ON articles.author_id = users.id
ORDER 
    BY users.username
     , articles.title~ what we are saying is that add a colum name count with each and every row comming put of the database containing the count of all the articles that user have posted. Sry for typo actually typing from mobile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options:

**FIRST**

Run second query to get articles data.

```
SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `id` IN (articles_published)
```

**SECOND**

Use `GROUP_CONCAT` on article title and content too, like on `id`. Separate with something, that won't be in article title or content. For example:

```
SELECT 
  articles.id, 
  articles.author_id,
  users.username,
  COUNT(articles.id) AS number_of_articles,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT articles.id) AS articles_id,
  GROUP_CONCAT(articles.title SEPARATOR '<--next article-->') AS articles_title,
  GROUP_CONCAT(articles.content SEPARATOR '<--next article-->') AS articles_content
FROM articles 
LEFT JOIN users ON articles.author_id = users.id
GROUP BY articles.author_id 
ORDER BY articles.published DESC;
```

And your PHP would look something like this.

```
foreach ($results as $result) {
  $article_ids      = explode(',', $result['articles_id']);
  $article_titles   = explode('<--next article-->', $result['articles_title']);
  $article_contents = explode('<--next article-->', $result['articles_content']);

  echo $result['username'].' wrote '.$result['number_of_articles'].' '.($result['number_of_articles']>1 ? 'articles' : 'article').'<br /><br />';

  foreach ($article_ids as $key => $article_id) {
    $title   = $article_titles[$key];
    $content = $article_contents[$key];

    echo $title.'<br />';
    echo $content.'<br /><br />';
  }

  echo '-----<br />';
}
```

Comment: #1: Run second query to get articles data. 
Problem with this is that you have to increment the index of the array[index]['articles_published'], this is very bad because you'll end up running the MySQL query: "SELECT * FROM `articles` WHERE `id` IN (articles_published)" in a loop, this is bad. Argg.

Comment: #2: Use GROUP_CONCAT on article title and content too, like on id. Separate with something, that won't be in article title or content. For example, I knew about this part. Still not what I want, think: Aggregate and Grouping.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. #1 is not good since it would run in loop.

Comment: Rene Korss can you explain the following to me: 

User A asks: "It's working, but not the way I'm looking for. The method you proposed erases all the data when grouping it. So I get only one result per activity because its merging everything."

User B answers: "The data from the fields you need to get can be gotten by using GROUP_CONCAT() function."

Comment: If I understand correctly: User A is saying that by just selecting `articles.title`, the result would be first title/content of all results (not all articles what belong to author). User B is basically saying to use `GROUP_CONCAT` like I did in #2 solution.

Comment: Korss, why does User B suggest GROUP_CONCAT(sa.activityID); in his answer. I see no Title or content here.

Comment: Hard to say, I can't see where you are taking this. But I guess, field `sa.activityID` is same as `articles.title` and `articles.content` in this case.

Comment: Korss, here's what User B wrote exactly: "You'd likely group on the item id of the item being modified - which in this case looks like: ua.imdbID.

Once you do that, you'll lose out on the other rows of data, so you'd use GROUP_CONCAT to get all related IDs.

GROUP_CONCAT(sa.activityID);"

What does this say to you?

Comment: To compare to current case: it says that grouping on `author_id` will lose all other articles title and content (except first). So, you have to use `GROUP_CONCAT` to get all articles data related to `author_id`.

Comment: Korss, based on this NEW information, what would you suggest.

Comment: Go with my #2 solution.

Comment: Rene Korss, can you explain this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14004322/intelligent-mysql-group-by-for-activity-streams, a bit similar. Uses GROUP_CONCAT and GROUP BY

Comment: This is what I want to achieve along with the data: Group when there are multiple items by a particular user within a certain time frame.